# Network manager no longer functional after most recent sudo apt-get upgrade

Tags: 14.04, network-manager, ethernet

I am on 14.04, kernel 3.13.0-64.generic #104.

I did `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and the network manager no longer works. Is anyone else experiencing this?

`sudo lshw -C network` shows that my ethernet device `eth0` is disabled.
I note that `dmesg` has the following notes regarding `eth0`.

```
eth0: RTL8168g/8111g at 0xffffc9...... .....  IRQ43
eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
.......
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

I am able to do `sudo ifconfig eth0 up`. `eth0` and `lo` show up in the output of `ifconfig`. It appears as 'UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST". inet6 addr and HWaddr for `eth0` are now populated with non-zero values. This also removes the "disabled" flag from `sudo lshw -C network`.

As a result of the above command, I see the following new notes in `dmesg` regarding `eth0`.

```
r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link up
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP):eth0: link became ready
```

Throughout all this, the network manager has the following behavior. The initial screen with connections is totally blank. The only viable buttons are "add" and "close." I click "add", then select "ethernet" (the default) from the dropdown. All five tabs are totally greyed out: All options in all tabs are greyed out, and all settings involving lists are totally empty. The only button I can click is "cancel."

I am at work, and the company uses 801.2x for security. I don't think that is the source of the problem because at this point I can't even see or create any connections in the network manager.

Another data point is that I reboot about once a week and `apt-get upgrade` every month.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try to boot up older kernel

Comment: @Serg Thanks for the suggestion. The problem persists with older kernels.

Comment: FWIW, I have just done the same thing today, and am seeing the exact same effect (and booting with older kernels also does not work). So, it seems this might be more than an individual-level issue.